# autofocus problem with my Nikon D3200

Tags: nikon-d3100

I have a Nikon D3200 camera and whilst it autofocuses using my Af-S Nikkor 18-70 mm attachment lens, the autofocus does not work when I attach my AF-Nikkor 70-330 mm lens and my AF Micro Nikkor 60 mm lens.
How do I resolve this because manually focusing with these 2 lens is not easy !

Answer (score 0):

> How do I resolve this because manually focusing with these 2 lens is not easy!

You buy a Nikon body with a built in AF motor in the body, or you buy AF-S lenses to use on your D3200.

The Nikon D3x00 and [D5x00 series cameras do not have AF motors built into the body](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67461/15871). To use autofocus with these cameras, including your D3200, you must use lenses with AF motors built into the lens. Such lenses include AF-S, AF-I, and AF-P models. Note that your D3200 is not compatible with AF-P lenses, but some of the newer D3x00 and D5x00 models are.

Nikon AF lenses do not have AF motors built into the lens. They have a mechanical linkage that connects to a screw drive on the camera that allows a motor built into the camera body to drive the focus mechanism in the lens. Nikon lenses with AF motors built into the lens are AF-S, AF-I, or AF-P lenses.